# get customer id by email magento2?

Tags: magento2, customer

I am using below code to get customer id by email

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

protected $_objectManager;
protected $currentCustomer;
protected $_customer; 
protected $_storeManager;    
 public function __construct(
    Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
)
{        
    $this->session = $customerSession;        
    $this->_customer = $customer;       
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager; 
}

 public function execute()
{
  $email = 'test@gmail.com';
 $customerModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
        $storeId = $this->getWebsiteId();
        $customerModel->setWebsiteId($storeId);
        $customerModel->loadByEmail($email);
        $userId = $customerModel->getId();
 }
 public function getWebsiteId(){
   return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
}
```

I am not getting customerid, Please anyone suggest me, how to get customer id by email.

Comment: Can you please upload your full code ? Or use my below code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this below code :

```
protected $_customer;
protected $_storemanager;
public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanager,
    .....
){
    .....
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_storemanager = $storemanager;
    ...
}
public function execute() {
    $email = 'test@test.com';
    $websiteID = $this->_storemanager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    $customer = $this->_customer->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteID)->loadByEmail($email);
    $customerId = $customer->getId();
}
```

Comment: I am also using same code, but not working for me, tell me what is the difference in my code

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: same again customer id is not returning

Comment: please check my updated answer. Remove var and generated folder

Comment: not working i tried that also, Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Customer\\Model\\ResourceModel\\CustomerRepository\\Interceptor::getByEmail()

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: same again, i am not getting it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83687/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-jafar-pinjar).

Answer (score 3):

There is another way you can get Customer id by Customer Email.In this use service contact Class `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface`

```
namespace {NameSpace};


class {YOUR_CLass}
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    )
    {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function  getCustomer()
    {

        try{
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->get('amit@gmail.com');
            $customerId = $customer->getId();
        }catch(\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $exception){

        }catch(\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $exception){

        }
        return $customer;
    }
}
```